# Meaning of the word wax in this context

Tags: word-meaning

I could not get it if it is a verb or an adjective.If it is a verb, to talk a lot in a way that expresses emotion or enthusiasm, shouldn't the word **euphoric** have written "**euphorically**" also ?

> Perhaps nowhere else in China more than in Beijing is the generation
>   gap more visible. Appalled by the current drive to “modernise”, many
>   older people still **wax** euphoric about Chairman Mao and the years
>   of sacrifice for the socialist revolution. But most youngsters disdain
>   socialist sacrifice and are more interested -like youngsters
>   everywhere - in money, motorbikes, fashion, video games and rock music
>   .

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21673/is-there-any-other-way-you-can-wax-as-you-do-when-you-wax-philosophical

Answer (score 1):

"wax" has three entries in English dictionaries. It can be a verb; with an adjective it means to become. Mostly used in expressions such as

- to wax lyrical/eloquent/sentimental

"to wax" indicates a change from a normal state into a special one.  Longman DCE does not indicate a style level, but I would say it is rare, sometimes used humorously and its use is limited to special changes in mood. You can't use it as a normal variant for "to become".

DCE has the example: Journalists wax lyrical about the band (used humorously).

As to etymology, the link given by pyobum is worth reading.

Comment: Good, but OP wants to know why *euphoric* and not *euphorically*.

Comment: "to wax" is used as a normal copula verb like to be/to become/to remain. And copula verbs  take an adjective as subject complement.